# SQL Trigger to add values of Two columns and store it in Third column

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i have a table with three columns say pqty,prqty and balqty.
what i want to do is, have to add values of pqty and prqty. and then it should be stored in balqty. while inserting or updating this table, each row must be affect.
i used this trigger, and it worked sometimes and most of times it wont. i dont know why.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tsl on stockledger
FOR update
AS declare @pqty int, @prqty int;
select @pqty=i.pqty from inserted i;
select @prqty=i.prqty from inserted i;
update Stockledger set balqty = (@pqty - @prqty) 
PRINT 'AFTER Update trigger fired.'
```

Comment: Your update statement updates all records. You don't want that.

Comment: It doesn't work because `inserted` is a *table*. It contains *multiple* rows, and each of those rows may have different `pqty` and `prqty` values. Heck, it's not even guaranteed that your two `select @local_variable=...` statements will even end up with consistent values from a single row.

Comment: Never under any circusmtance set the value form inserted to a asscalar variable,. You will often have mulitple records in the samet ransaction and even if you don't now, eventually you will.  SQL server does not process row-by row in triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a good use of a trigger. Instead, if you have the capacity, consider using a computed column (with PERSISTED to enhance performance):

```
ALTER TABLE StockLedger DROP COLUMN balqty;
ALTER TABLE StockLedger ADD COLUMN balqty AS pqty - prqty PERSISTED;
```

Comment: Much much better than the trigger solution.

Comment: I will alos point out that while the code above indicated the OP was subtracting, the text said that he wanted to add. So if you really wanted to add use a + instead of a - when creting the persisted column.